# In TSPC IPv6 tunneling, is a tunnel broker required for IPv4 to IPv4 communication?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, tunnel, ipv4

I am new to embedded systems and trying to add support for the IPv6 network availability in my new product but that is not my concern now.

First of all, my system is connected to an IPv4 ISP and I want to communicate with the System with an IPv6 address, so I would need a tunnel broker, which will make the IPv6 network available for my IPv4 PC.

When I am trying to communicate with the system's IPv6 network my data (packets) would be sent through the tunnel broker which would work as NAT and drop the IPv4 header and forward the IPv6 header and data to the IPv6 network.

But I have a question:

If my PC has an IPv4 address and I am trying to communicate with the system with an IPv4 address then will my packets (data) be transferred through the tunnel broker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your have an IPv6 tunnel broker then your IPv6 packets will be put inside IPv4 packets. Those packets are then sent to the IPv4 address of the tunnel broker, where the IPv4 header is removed and the inner IPv6 packet is forwarded to the IPv6 internet as usual. No NAT is involved.

IPv4 is completely independent of IPv6. IPv4 packets will in no way be affected when using an IPv6 tunnel broker.

Comment: Thanks Sander for your reply,
Btw I figured out the solution.